# Test that bundle install creates extension

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, bundler, minitest

I maintain a Ruby gem that compiles a Rust extension.  It works on the majority of Linux and Windows systems but doesn't build on Macs.  The problem happens during the bundle/gem install process.

I need a way to add to the project's test suite a **build and install gem** success test.  Preferably not installing it locally into the system but into a temporary directory.  The tests should also verify the linked library file exists upon gem install.

If you need more context for the question here is my Github issue for resolving the cross-platform gem extension building: https://github.com/danielpclark/faster_path/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled across https://rubybench.org/ and they have a benchmark for Bundler with a temporary directory:

```
require_relative 'support/benchmark_bundler.rb'
require 'bundler/cli'

noop_gem = Pathname(__FILE__).expand_path + '../gems/noop-gem'

Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  Dir.chdir(dir) do
    File.write('Gemfile', <<-GEMFILE)
      source 'https://rubygems.org'
      gem 'rails'
      gem 'noop-gem', path: '#{noop_gem}'
    GEMFILE
    system("bundle install --quiet")

    Benchmark.do_benchmark('bundle exec gem') do
      system("bundle exec noop-gem")
    end
  end
end
```

This basically does what I need, I just need to change the benchmark part for verifying extension building.

UPDATE: This is becoming a real pain to test and isn't working as planned.